# Getting non-view data from a custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a custom adapter that I'm using to populate a ListView. I have an `onItemClick()` set on the ListView item that changes the displayed fragment to something else.

I want to pass data to the new fragment from the ListView item, but I don't want to get any of that data from the visible views if I can help it. The custom adapter parses a JSONObject to get the data to populate the ListView. So is there a way that I can access that underlying data outside of the adapter class?

More specifically, I'm trying to put the necessary underlying ListView data into a Bundle and pass that Bundle from the ListView item up to the activity, to then pass into the new fragment.

I also want to get it from the `getView()` method so I don't have to duplicate code in another custom public method within the adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that if your custom adapter overrides the `getItem(int position)` method and there you should return the object at the given position within your adapter's dataset.
After that you can get the clicked data using `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` on the `ListView` by calling this:

`parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)`   -> and this is your data corresponding to your clicked item.
You just have to cast that returned object to whatever your class is and do what you want to it..
good luck and I hope it helps!

Comment: Good idea. I can do the JSON parsing in the getItem() method and just pass that Bundle into getView().

Comment: but isn't the json already parsed in the adapter? You should use a management class to do the parsing and pass the list of parsed objects into the adapter as its dataset.. or isn't the JSON values your adapter's dataset?

Comment: I'm passing in a JSON array to the adapter and parsing it in the getView() method.

Comment: I'd advise against directly retrieving the data on an index basis from the adapter, since it does not take into account any header or footer views. In stead, get it from the `ListView`, using `getItemAtPostion(int)` and cast the object to whatever you're populating the adapter with. The `ListView` will take care of correctly offsetting the index based on the number of header views. On a side note: you'll probably want to do as little as possibly in `getView(...)` to get the best user experience.

Comment: That makes sense. My ListView did get a little laggy at times. The reason I'm trying to get data from the adapter is because I need a Bundle of Strings, which I can't get from calling getItemAtPosition(int).

Comment: It is ok to get the data from the adapter, what is not ok is to parse the data in the adapter.. the data should be already parsed when is set as the adapter's dataset..

Comment: Right. I'm putting a JSON Array into the adapter, so I guess technically it's parsed (it's a JSONArray). I've just been doing all the getJSONObject().getString("tag") calls in the getView in the adapter.

Comment: Well that's the issue( getJSONObject().getString("tag")  ) .. you have to create your own Model, a custom data structure and create objects of it so it will be way faster to say myCustomObject.getTag() than what you've just wrote..

Comment: Just so I got this right. What do you mean when you say a Model or a management class? Would I have to do a for loop to pick the JSON data I need from the array before sending it to the adapter?

Comment: Yes, that should be the idea.. Model = the parsed data; Management class = class that parses the JSON and construct the model :)